# Can't get Flutter package flutter_pagewise to work

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to use the `flutter_pagewise` package for Flutter, but I can't get it to work. I need a Gridview with more than 600 images.

- I have an folder with all 600 images (~80kb for each)
- I declare this folder as Asset in pubspec.yaml
- I created a json file with the paths of the images

**My code**

Json part

```
Future<List> getDemoImagesJson() async {
    String demoImages = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
        .loadString("assets/demo/demo.json");
    final jsonResult = json.decode(demoImages);
    List images = [];
    for (var i in jsonResult) {
      images.add(i);
    }

    print(images);
    return images;
  }
```

Widget part

```
Container(
    child: PagewiseGridView.count(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    pageSize: 6,
    crossAxisCount: 3,
    mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
    crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
    childAspectRatio: 0.555,
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
    noItemsFoundBuilder: (_) => Text("Nichts gefunden"),
    itemBuilder: (context, entry, index) {
      print(entry);
      return Text("Hey");
    },
    pageFuture: (pageIndex) {
      return getDemoImagesJson();
    },
  ))
```

I only see a loading spinner....and nothing else. Where is the error?

Comment: does `print(images);` show anything ?

Comment: Yes, it shows a List of the paths of my images. Like this: ["assets/path/image1", "assets/path/image2"] ....

Comment: check out my answer I havent used this plugin I just read the docs and their example, probably needs some debugging but youll get the idea 

Comment: since you solved your question I deleted my answer to that you will be able to delete your question as well